# How to change project properties to run locally?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I am working on CVS in a web project on Eclipse, Currently in the address bar I see: `http://Remote Server Address:8080/myproject/`.

When I needed to test some changes, I had to synchronize and commit to be able to test.

I want to have my own version of the project on my workspace that is different than the server, and my address bar looks like: `http://localhost:8080/MyProject/index.jsp`.

I tried to copy and paste, but whenever I put it in the workspace it detects the address of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the server location, Just right click on the project click run is server and select your local tomcat server and you are done.
Whenever you are done with all the testing commit the code.
If any doubt update here.